# How to run code immediately when element gets rendered upon satisfying v-show condition?

Tags: vue.js

General question here not tied to a particular piece of code: I need to know the coordinates of an element in order to scroll down to it.

This element has a `v-show` condition and is hidden on page load, but user can click a button that will reveal the element (by satisfying the `v-show` condition).

Problem: if I immediately calculate the coordinates of the element when user clicks the button, I do NOT get the correct coordinates. I have to wait for a second or two with a `setTimeout()` to finally get the right coordinates.

Question: is there a way to make `Vue` do this as soon as possible, instead of making it wait some arbitrary length of time?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re showing an element and then wanting to scroll to it, you could try using the [`nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) callback:

```js
// Set data that will show other element, i.e.
// this.showOtherElement = true;

// Use nextTick callback to scroll to element in the next tick
this.$nextTick().then(() => {
    // Put code to scroll to element here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to work though. Still getting wrong coordinates immediately upon click, and correct ones after a couples seconds, even when I wrapped the whole code in `this.$nextTick().then(() => {})`

Comment: @drake035 You must doing something else wrong because this is correct answer and should be accepted. https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-run-code-immediately-when-element-gets-rendered-upon-satisfying-v-show-condition-4pcly

Comment: Agreed. @drake035, I think you need to show us some code so we can actually diagnose your issue, rather than giving us some abstract overview. From [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): “if your problem is _with_ code you've written, you should include some.”